# How does apple's EFI compare to the UEFI standard?

Tags: firmware

Apple's EFI in macs were the first implementation of EFI by Intel but then Intel revised their work and made UEFI for PC's which is newer and possibly better. I wanted to know if Apple's EFI has been receiving updates through the years or is it outdated compared to UEFI ?